# Kendo TreeView with checkbox

Tags: kendo-ui

****I have a kendo checkbox treeview with parent and child nodes, in  my asp.net mvc web app. The problem is when i uncheck the child node the parent node also unchecks automaticaly. is there any way to avoid this problem thank you in advance.****

Comment: Your question is too broad. It is highly unlikely that you will receive a useful answer. Instead, it is recommended that you post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will significantly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Make the CheckChildren to flase

@{Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                        .ExpandAll(false)
                        .Name("PrivelegeTreeView")
                        .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
                                   .Name("checkedFiles")
                                   **.CheckChildren(false)**
                                    )